# Resharper formatting chained method

Tags: resharper, code-formatting

Is there a setting in R# to format chained method to start at the same character of the class instantiated.

What I want:

```
var foo = new FooDataBuilder()
              .WithDate(myDate)
              .WithBar(myBar)
              .Build();
```

What R# is giving me:

```
var foo = new FooDataBuilder()
    .WithDate(myDate)
    .WithBar(myBar)
    .Build();
```

Comment: No, there is no such setting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Resharper 7.1.2, you can get the following formatting:

```
var foo = new FooDataBuilder().WithDate(myDate)
                              .WithBar(myBar)
                              .Build();
```

By setting the following Resharper options:

`Code Editing`->`C#`->`Formatting Style`->`Line Breaks and Wrapping`->`Line Wrapping`->`Wrap chained method calls` to `Chop always`

and

enable `Code Editing`->`C#`->`Formatting Style`->`Other`->`Align Multiline Constructs`->`Chained method calls`

I don't think you can align with `FooDataBuilder()` unless you do it manually. *(This has been confirmed by @Dmitry Osinovskiy from Jetbrains so this may be the closest you're going to get to what you want.)*

Comment: For ReSharper 2017.3 the section "Align Multiline Constructs" with the setting "Chained Method Calls" can be found under "Tabs, Indents, Alignment".