# Resharper settings for method chaining

Tags: resharper, method-chaining

Is it possible to configure resharper to chop all methods in a method chain

e.g.

```
var query = list.Where(x => true).Select(x => x);
```

becomes

```
var query = list
            .Where(x => true)
            .Select(x => x);
```

If not, then is it possible to configure resharper to ignore method chains when formatting? So I can chop the text manually without having to worry about resharper re-formatting it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450199/resharper-formatting-chained-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to align `.Where` under `list`.

As for chopping, there is an option in `ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping -> Line Wrapping` called `Wrap chained method calls`. If you set it to `Chop always`, it would chop, but it uses a slightly different formatting:

```
var query = list.Where(x => true)
                .Select(x => x);
```

If you leave it to `Chop if long` (default value), then it wouldn't re-chop your code unless it would be very long (more than `Right margin` option, which is in the same option group mentioned above).