# Is there any way to force resharper to align chained method calls in a specific way

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, resharper

Lets say I have the following code in C#

```
        var stringList = GetListOfStrings();
        var firstString = stringList.Where(s => true)
                                    .Where(s => true)
                                    .Where(s => true)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

It doesn't do very much, but it's formatted in the way I like by ReSharper and by Resharpers Code Cleanup feature.

Now lets say I rewrite that code to just call the method `GetListOfStrings` without assigning it to a variable first. In this situation Resharper formats it as follows:

```
            var firstString = GetListOfStrings()
                .Where(s => true)
                .Where(s => true)
                .Where(s => true)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there anyway to change this so ReSharper formats it as below instead?

```
            var firstString = GetListOfStrings().Where(s => true)
                                                .Where(s => true)
                                                .Where(s => true)
                                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

I'm using the ReSharper 8 Beta and VS 2013 preview if it makes any difference.

Comment: Similar question to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450199/resharper-formatting-chained-method/15453305#15453305

Answer (score 10):

I think you're looking for the "Chained Method Calls" option under the "Align Multiline Constructs" header here:

[image]

Comment: For ReSharper 2017.3 the section "Align Multiline Constructs" with the setting "Chained Method Calls" can be found under "Tabs, Indents, Alignment".

Answer (score 7):

With Resharper, you can use the following options:

`Code Editing`->`C#`->`Formatting Style`->`Line Breaks and Wrapping`->`Line Wrapping`->`Wrap chained method calls` to `Chop always`

and

enable `Code Editing`->`C#`->`Formatting Style`->`Other`->`Align Multiline Constructs`->`Chained method calls`

Comment: For ReSharper 2017.3 the section "Align Multiline Constructs" with the setting "Chained Method Calls" can be found under "Tabs, Indents, Alignment".